# Why does my refresh control retain my UIViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, dealloc

I have a simple refresh control which I add to the view of my view controller which causes it to never be dealloced. What could be the cause of it ?

```
   pullRefresh = [[ScrollRefresh alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, -30, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 2)];
   [pullRefresh addTarget:self selector:@selector(refreshFeed)];
   [self.feedTable addSubview:pullRefresh];
```

**ScrollRefresh.h**

```
@interface ScrollRefresh : UIView<DragMenuDelegate>{

    int width;
    UIView *clip;
    id target;
    SEL selector;
}


-(void)addTarget:(id)t selector:(SEL)sel;
```

**ScrollRefresh.m**

```
@implementation ScrollRefresh

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.backgroundColor = kClearColor;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;


        clip = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, self.frame.size.height)];
        clip.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2;
        clip.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(kTweetColor, 1.0);
        [self addSubview:clip];



    }
    return self;
}

-(void)addTarget:(id)t selector:(SEL)sel{

    target = t;
    selector = sel;

}

-(void)didScroll:(float)o{

    if(o<0)o *= -1;
    width = o*2.8;
    if(width > self.frame.size.width) width = self.frame.size.width;

    if(width < self.frame.size.width){
        ChangeFrameWidth(clip, width);
    }


}


-(void)endRefreshing{

    if(width >= self.frame.size.width-5){

         #pragma clang diagnostic push
         #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
        if(target)[target performSelector:selector withObject:nil];
         #pragma clang diagnostic pop
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target in `ScrollRefresh` is defined as strong. Add `__weak` modifier to it.

Comment: Damn I swear I added `__weak` 2 minutes ago and it still did not get dealloced.Turns out this was the culprit, not the blocks and self references from the question you answered before. Thanks Leo, you helped me a lot today.